# How to make a list of big strings?

Tags: c#

What should I use to create a list of big strings?`List<string> myList=new List<string>();
myList.Add("very big string goes here");`
Note that this way is giving an overflow error in csharp. What should I use instead of it?

Example string `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e625d5fdde4f78f8b3df28"),
    "ID" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
    "UserID" : "abcdef",
    "BaseFileName" : "insert",
    "FileID" : "insert.00001.txt.txt",
    "FileData" : "��/F\u000f"
}`

Comment: Provide example string, error message details & example code to reproduce your issue. I think overflow error only thrown by numeric value types instead of string.

Comment: You could use the [System.Text.StringBuilder class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx). E.g. `List<System.Text.StringBuilder> mylist = new List<System.Text.StringBuilder>(); System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();  sb.Append("break string down into");  sb.Append("strings of lesser length"); mylist.Add(sb);`. Sorry for so much code, I don't want to put it as an answer in case its not what you want.

Comment: The length of the string has _zero_ to do with how you might store the _reference_ to that string. A different kind of list isn't going to change the fact that, apparently, you are trying to create a string larger than .NET will allow. The only way around that is to create a new data structure that understands longer strings. The next thing you need to do is figure out what you're going to _do_ with a string that big. No user is going to ever read it, so there's that.

Comment: I have given an example string

Comment: And the string you posted in your question isn't anywhere close to large enough to cause any sort of error. You really need to post a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces whatever problem you actually have, because it sounds like you don't really understand exactly what the problem you have is. Your problem may not be string-related at all.

Comment: If you want to store a large string (I believe .NET's limit is 2GB per string), larger than .NET can natively hold, then you're effectively looking at either splitting up the string or going with a `byte[]` and reading from a `Stream`. The second approach would be recommended if you're receiving a very large packet of data via JSON.

Comment: Show the actual, complete code where you do the `myList.Add()` call with the string, or is the string you are adding in a variable?